# git merge but keep incoming changes unstaged

Tags: git

Say my current branch is `feature-foo` and the working directory is clear (there are no modified files). And I merge another branch `feature-baz` on it by: `git merge feature-baz`.

What I want is that all the changes from the branch `feature-baz` are applied to the files on my current branch but the **merge** commit should not happen. So, when I do `git status`, I should see all the modified files still unstaged.

Is this possible in Git? If yes, how...?

I want to do this because this way, I would be able to do the changes into the code during my code-review process. And then do a manual commit instead of an automated merge commit which is done by Git.

Thanks

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--no-commit` and `--no-ff` options with `git merge`:

```
$ git merge --no-commit --no-ff feature-baz
```

`--no-ff` ensures that the merge *would* create a commit, even if a fast-forward is possible. `--no-commit` updates your working directory, but stops before creating the merge commit.

Comment: Note, though, that the updated files will be staged (except for any conflicted files that would have forced `--no-commit` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `git reset HEAD^` after merging with `git merge`.

Important thing is that you merge (this will create merge commit, as you know) and then use `git reset HEAD^` - `HEAD^` will cause to "revert" to commit before last commit on current branch (!), so right before merge commit.

All changes from that commit will be:

- moved to index (shown as added) if you use `git reset --soft HEAD^`
- completely unstaged (shown as unstaged) if you use `git reset --medium HEAD^`
- if you use `git reset --hard HEAD^` changes will be removed completely, from GIT and from disk, so you do not want that.

Side note: `--medium` is default option, so you can omit it.

So you want to do:

```
git merge feature-baz
git reset HEAD^
```